# TSQL Comparing 2 uniqueidentifier values not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier, null-uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to compare 2 uniqueidentifier values as shown in the query below. However, if one value is null and one value isn't, the result is 'same'?! I'm sure that both values are uniqueidentifiers, and have also tried casting both values to uniqueidentifier to make absolutely sure. The 2 values being compared are coming from different databases with different collations. Does the collation make any difference? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
select [result] = case when 
    [target].StaffID <> [source].StaffID then 'different' 
    else 'same' 
    end
from
    ...
```

If I replace the <> with an = the query then thinks that 2 null values don't match.

**EDIT:**

I used:

```
declare @empty uniqueidentifier
set @empty = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
... isnull(somevalue, @emtpy) <> isnull(othervalue, @empty) ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is neither equal to something nor equal to nothing.  Generally you'd check for null values by comparing with `IS NULL`.  For example,

```
somefield IS NULL
```

You could look into using `COALESCE` for what you're trying to do -- just make sure you use the same data types (in this case UniqueIdentifier):

```
...
  case 
    when coalesce(t.StaffID,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') <> 
         coalesce(t2.StaffID,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    then 'different' 
    else 'same' 
  end
...
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/181e9d/1

Answer (score 0):

null is more of an unknown, it's not really a value. Unfortunately SQL will tell you that null = null is false.

Basically you have to cast nulls to empty strings than you can compare.  We use IFNULL(value, replacement) to do that...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Hope this helps.

```
select case when null = null then 'equal' else 'not equal' end
```

Above will be "not equal"

```
select case when ISNULL(null, '') = ISNULL(null, '') then 'equal' else 'not equal' end
```

This one will be "equal"

And finally your case...

```
select [result] = case when 
    ISNULL([target].StaffID, '') <> ISNULL([source].StaffID, '') then 'different' 
    else 'same' 
    end
from
```

Comment: If StaffId's type is `UniqueIdentifier`, you cannot use `ISNULL` with a blank string -- you'll get a data type conversion error.